# How to Store dynamic field data in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to store dynamic fields value to the database like bellow format,

```
"items": [
    {
        "item_id" : 6,
        "description" : "",
        "quantity" : "1"
    },{
        "item_id" : 5,
        "description" : "",
        "quantity" : "60"
    }
]
```

kindly guide me with code, how can in store them using useState hook thankyou!.
Here are the fields of these values
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zyqm4.jpg

Note: I am using functional react components

Comment: So you can use the hook `useRef()` it does not trigger render if data changes, you can you that to simulate a database.

Comment: @Abdul Can you be more specific please ? Where do you want to store ? Database or front state ? And where does these items comes and how are they updated ?

Comment: I want to get the value from front end form fields then i want to sent them using axios api to the backend  you can look at this image https://imgur.com/SXvZTg1

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create a Model for your items and then you could create a list of those objects, serialize them and post them into your db.
Example of the model:

```
class Item {
    constructor(item_id, description, quantity) {
        this.item_id = item_id;
        this.description = description;
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }
}

export default Item;
```

Now when someone is filling your form you could use `onSubmit` function to create a new instance of the model and add it into your list, after the user is done using the form you can have a `Submit` to `post` it into the `db`

(this is one way to achieve your goal)